# replacing the value of one column conditional on two other columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame df:

```
year ID  category 
1     1    0        
2     1    1        
3     1    1        
4     1    0        
1     2    0        
2     2    0        
3     2    1        
4     2    0
```

I want to create a new column such that: for a particular 'year' if the 'category' is 1, the 'new-category' will be always 1 for the upcoming years:

```
year ID  category new_category
1     1    0        0
2     1    1        1
3     1    1        1
4     1    0        1
1     2    0        0
2     2    0        0
3     2    1        1
4     2    0        1
```

I have tried if-else condition but I am getting the same 'category' column

```
for row in range(1,df.category[i-1]):
    df['new_category'] = df['category'].replace('0',df['category'].shift(1))
```

But I am not getting the desired column

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TRY:

```
df['new_category'] = df.groupby('ID')['category'].cummax()
```

OUTPUT:

```
   year  ID  category  new_category
0     1   1         0             0
1     2   1         1             1
2     3   1         1             1
3     4   1         0             1
4     1   2         0             0
5     2   2         0             0
6     3   2         1             1
7     4   2         0             1
```